# is while loop infinite

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to build a list of inputs from several files. I need the list to consist only of the first file with a given basename. So if I a & b were folders, and there were "C:\a\file1.ext", "C:\b\file1" and "C:\c\file1" and I had a list of names file1, file2 and so on, I would want the script to find file1 in C:\a\file1.ext and then move on to the next name in the list. In some cases file-x.ext may not be in C:\a or C:\c or C:\b.

I'm setting a condition to count the file once it's base name is found in the list. Once the count = 1 it exits the while loop, resets the count to 0, and goes to the next name in the list, adding the first instance only of the file name to a new input list. The code I have seems to keep running so I think I have an internal loop but I thought setting count to 0 outside of the while loop would prevent this:

```
count = 0
for name in dbfOnlyLst:
    for file in fileLst:
        while count < 1:
            if  os.path.basename(file) == name+".dbf":
                values.add(file)
                count += 1
    count = 0
inList = list(values)
```

Comment: yep. edited it just before you posted your comment. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, this while loop is infinite if any file does not have the filename you're looking for. `file` never changes inside your `while` loop, so the condition can never become true if it isn't at first.

Comment: What do you think `os.path.basename` does?

Comment: what is the point of your while loop to begin with, it doesn't seem like you need it

Comment: the point is that I need to have the first file with the basename and not the subsequent ones. These files have had the subsequent files already appended to them. I want the while loop to count the file name up to one time, add it to a list so I can export these unique files to another location. Once count = 1 the loop should move to the next file name until the for loops are exhausted.

Comment: @ cricket I believe os.path.basename gives me file1.ext from C:\a\file1.ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop will be infinite because it only achieves the exit condition if `os.path.basename(file) == name+".dbf"` returns `True`. If it isn't true, then count will never be updated, and the loop will perform the same conditional check over and over again.

`os.path.basename(file)` just returns the filename without the path -- it doesn't continue on to the next file in your list, so there's no reason why performing that check multiple times will do anything different.

So, you don't really need that `while` loop at all. You're just trying to check if each file in your `fileLst` object is equal to the filename you're looking for, so just iterate over `fileLst`.

And since you want to just record the first match of your base filename, you can use the `break` keyword to exit your inner loop early, as soon as you find a match. This way you won't keep iterating over `fileLst` and will move on to the next `name` in `dbfOnlyLst`

```
for name in dbfOnlyLst:
    for file in fileLst:
        if  os.path.basename(file) == name+".dbf":
            values.add(file)
            break # only add the first match
inList = list(values)
```

Comment: but won't the subsequent files with the same basenames get added to the list?

Comment: the `break` means the inner `for` loop immediately ends, so it will continue with the next iteration of `for name in dbfOnlyLst`.

Comment: Ahhh, I thought break would exit the entire loop. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: `break` only exits the most immediate loop, not *all* loops it's inside of

Comment: I'm a little curious why my post got a down vote. What's that all about?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been mentioned in comments, but I figured I would demonstrate it.
Your loop keeps going until x is no longer less than 1.  This only happens when a file is found with ".dbf" in it, because that leads to x += 1.  If a file with ".dbf" is not found, the loop will keep running.

For example...

```
count = 0
x = 12  # my imitation of finding a file with .dbf in it
while count < 1:
    if x == 12:
        print("yes")
        x += 1

... 'yes'
```

This is when the loop would end.  However, if x didn't equal 12...

```
count = 0
x = 8
while count < 1:
    if x == 12:
        print("yes")
        x += 1
    else:
        print("no")  # will show you are stuck in the loop

... 'no'
... 'no'
... 'no'
... 'no'
# And so on...
```

I would recommend what @xgord said with avoiding the while loop.  I answered this just so you could see what's going on "behind the scenes".  I hope this helped

Comment: Got it Just. I really didn't think about the condition not being met as a possible issue.  thx!

Comment: no problem.  Having a second set of eyes look at something can be really helpful.  I hope I helped